Tooltip('$x','$y') only renders $y on Multichart(Bokeh)
On a Multichart Vbar setup,where the same consolidated dataframe is shared by all the charts,adding hovertooltip on the vbar to indicate the x,y values results in showing only the $y value and not the $x value.
1.Adding tooltips=[("$x", '$y')] as argument to  figure()
plot_totalall = figure(title="TotalAll_oiExposure",
                       x_range=(optionData_df['Strike'].min(), optionData_df['Strike'].max()),
                        y_range=(optionData_df["total_Greeks2"].min(), optionData_df["total_Greeks2"].max()),
                        tools="hover",
                        tooltips=[("$x", '$y')])

2.Adding Vbar to the Hovertool as renderer
     vbar_totalall = plot_totalall.vbar(x=initData_totalallvex['x'], top=initData_totalallvex['y'], width=5,
                                    fill_color=initData_totalallvex['colors'])
hover_totalall = HoverTool(tooltips=[('$x','$y')], renderers= [vbar_totalall])
plot_totalall.add_tools(hover_totalall)  



If I see it correctly, it is pairs of variable name and variable value. Try tooltips=[('x coordinate','$x'),('y coordinate','$y')]

The above comment is correct, the output you are seeing is exactly the expected output per the documentation (in the "list of tuples" format, the first element is a label)
